# graphical vs. analytical solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i am currently refreshing my knowledge on ODEs, because usually I just usw them without thinking about it. With this simple example
$$ \frac{dx}{dt}=−2⋅x^2$$

I wanted to look at some particular solutions graphically first. If, for example, I start with x(0)=0, the derivative is zero and x(t) is zero for all times t. For a higher initial value, e.g. x(0)=2 the derivative is negative and x(t) sinks asymptotically towards 0. starting with a negative initial value, e.g. x(0)=-2, x(t) should sink towards -inf with increasing pace, because the derivative gets more and more negative.

However, if I solve this ODE analytically, I obtain
$$x(t)=\frac{1}{2t+x_{0}^{-1}}$$
If I now insert a negative x(0), the graph raises towards zero. And does not fit my graphical solution.

I am sorry if this question is trivial, but I don't really know what I did wrong here.

Comment: If $x_0 > 0$ then $x(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$. But if $x_0<0$ then your graph should have a vertical asymptote at $t = -\frac{1}{2x_0}$ such that $x \to -\infty$ when approaching from the left. If $x(t)$ isn't decreasing on the interval around $t=0$ then there probably is a mistake with your plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=-2x^2  \implies x(t)=\dfrac{1}{2t+C}$$

Notice that you cannot simply plug the initial conditions into the differential equation. Notice that you're given $x(0)=k \ | k \ne 0$, you're supposed to plug that information into the expression for $x(t)$ to get a value for $C$. Notice that $x(t)$ can never be $0$. It only approaches $0$ either as $t\to \infty$ or $C$ is a very-very large number as a Googol($10^{100}$) or a Googolplex($10^{\text{Googol}}$), but in the latter case the value of $C$ is already known to you.

Have a look at this graph here which describes the slope field of the ODE and the solution with varying values of $C$, with the transformation: $(x, t) \to (y, x)$ .[Slope Field and Graph of ODE](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3qndakyjbs).